# Is it possible to rent a virtual instance of Windows/XP/Vista/7 in the cloud on pay as you go basis?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am a software developer and I need to test my software on different OS all the time. I am using free VPC images from IE6 compat kit from Microsoft but they have only limited options of Windows Versions (Win XP SP3 and some restricted version of Vista).

I need a service where I could rent a Virtual OS in the cloud and connect via Remote Dektop. Use for couple of hours and then discard all the stuff I have been doing there.

I tried using Amazon S3 but they only have Windows Server 2003

Anyone knows of such a service that would offer different XP/Vista/7 versions ?

Comment: Sorry, but shopping type questions are discouraged on SU. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/not-the-shopping

Comment: Can't you get a MSDN account and get lincenses to test it on each version?

Comment: @random: His question may well be "does this type of thing exist?" in which case its not too localized at all. I think its an interesting and valid question.

Comment: Question is still about available webservices, which is off-topic. But since it's a shopping slant on OS in the cloud, localised to shopping. @mic

Comment: Oh well. I understand it can be seen as something where companies would be able to pitch this sort of service and get free advertising from this page. But seriously I have been looking at this problem for months and have not found a suitable solution. I was hoping that someone would point out a solution for this problem - surely testing   software on multiple OS is important issue?

Comment: @Janusz: it is important, but this isn't the site for it.  it seems better suited for a discussion forum than for the trilogy.  although it's possible the question has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/49897/remote-computer-renting-moving-my-desktop-to-the-cloud

Comment: bummer, was looking for the same thing.  haven't found anything yet.  sorry to see this question closed.